# iOS NSString - Creating upper case based on locale

Tags: ios, nsstring, uppercase, nslocale

My iOS application has language selection option.
Its a server based application that receives all the strings from server that are to be displayed in the app.
In one of the view, i've to convert text to "upper case", for that I'm using NSString's upperCaseString method. This is working good for English. But for other languages like French, Chinese, Russian, German etc, it might create problem. So, I've to use "uppercaseStringWithLocale" to provider appropriate upper case string.
My question is how to create the NSLocate and pass it to "upperCaseStringWithLocale" method based on the language name. I know what's the language of the app that user has selected. Can I create locale object based on language name.?

Comment: A locale and a language do not have a 1-to-1 correspondence. You will need to use a locale code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
NSString *theLocaleIdentifier = @"es_ES_PREEURO";
[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:theLocaleIdentifier];
```

Comment: Can I get the map of language and the locale identifiers that I can maintain in the app?

Comment: @Satyamsvv You can get all the locale identifiers using `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`

Comment: @Satyamsvv You can also get a specific locale identifier if you know the languace code and country code using `[NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleLanguageCode: @"en", NSLocaleCountryCode: @"US"}];`